# how to show all message on selected div in jquery

Tags: jquery

I create a chat function. here if i write something then it show on chat div. But my problem is if i write again then second message replace on first message. I want to show all message on chat div. Like chat

test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dhuronto</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#message').keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13 ){
if($(this).val()!=0)
    {
    e.preventDefault();//use this to prevent default behavior
    calculate();
    }
   }
   });
});

function calculate()
{
$.post(
"test_1.php",
$('#message').serialize(),
function(response)
{
$("#chat").html(response);
});
$('#message').val("");
}



</script>
</head>
    <body>
    <div id="chat" style=" width: 300px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: auto">

        </div>
        <textarea id="message" name="chat_message"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

test_1.php

```
<?php

$message=$_POST['chat_message'];

echo "$message";

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `append` instead. `html` replaces all content.

```
$.post("test_1.php", $('#message').serialize(), function(response) {
    $("#chat").append($message.val() + '<br/>')
              .scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight);
});
```

You can add a line break after each message, this they will be in a new line.
And use `scrollTop` to make the scroll down after enter a new message.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YNy9m/1)

Comment: thanks for your response. Here is also a problem, If i input so many message then my last message don't show. I need to scroll down to see last message. I want that if div space fill up then scroll move on down and show my last message clearly.

Answer (score 1):

`html` replaces the contents, you want to `append`. Change:

```
$("#chat").html(response);
```

to:

```
$("#chat").append(response);
```

Comment: Thanks all for your kind response. Here is also a problem, If i input so many message then my last message don't show. I need to scroll down to see last message. I want that if div space fill up then scroll move on down and show my last message clearly.

Answer (score 0):

in place of

```
$("#chat").html(response);
```

you can use

```
$("#chat").append(response);
```

jquery html is replace the whole html and jquery append is add other html tag or html value

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here is also a problem, If i input so many message then my last message don't show. I need to scroll down to see last message. I want that if div space fill up then scroll move on down and show my last message clearly.